# React reading json and converting field to string

Tags: javascript, json, string, reactjs

I am using React to try and pull logos from a local file, but in order to do that, I need to pull the field from json data and convert it into a string.

So for example, I have                     `<td width='60%'><Link to={item.id}>{item.id.toUpperCase()}</Link></td>`

I know normal javascript won't really run here, so I can't try the JSON.stringify() function. I am new to react so please bear with me if I am asking super simple questions.

Also, is there a way to use javascript with react? I did some google searches and never received a clear-cut answer aside from using Babel.

Comment: javascript will work in react , where did you read the following statement `I know normal javascript won't really run here`?

Comment: It is really disappointing when someone is using react and don't know what actually it is and language/technology behind it.

Comment: Hey relax man I’m a noobie picking up something never had the chance of learning before.. trying to self teach is hard when there’s scattered resources. I guess I could have worded it better, javascript is turned into babel through a converter but not running js directly. Correct me if I’m wrong please, or don’t bother replying if you’ve got a smart ass comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is a way to use javascript with react we call it JSX.

for building sample react app you can do the following :

```
npm install -g create-react-app (-g installs it globally)
mkdir create-react-app myApp
```

then go inside the myApp directory and do

```
npm start
```

you can also refer
 https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#before-we-start

Comment: Thank you, someone who has led me into the right direction. Appreciate the patience and kindness to a noobie genuinely trying to learn

Answer (score 1):

Javascript will work.

I recommend you read into [how JSX works](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

So, if you want to stringify `text` in `<td>text</td>`, you can just use

`<td>{JSON.stringify(text)}</td>` for example.

We might need more of your code, I'm not exactly sure what/where you're trying to parse to JSON.

Comment: So, the code is importing a json file and I’m using the value of field ID like student id and try to pull the image from a local file. But I can’t seem to figure out how to stringify the field I’m pulling to add a .png to it